# Missing many components after a fresh install

Tags: 14.04, unity, system-installation, software-installation, chromebook

I have a fresh, basic installation of Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity running through crouton on a new Chromebook, a Toshiba Chromebook 2 (CB35). You end up simply opening a chronos Chrome shell and calling

```
sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -r Trusty -t Unity
```

Upon installation, I immediately noticed that Gnome Terminal was not installed, or Ubuntu's Software Center or Software & Updates and others. I'm a first time Linux user so I used NetSurf to try to do a search and see what I could do but after a Google search but it kept refreshing, or re-sending the search before results appeared. I switched to ChromeOs and ended up using XTerm to install gnome terminal and the software center and grab a stable Chrome.

Now I'm trying to use Unity Tweak Tool to, well, tweak and I'm getting a lot of missing schema's from com.canonical.*. I've addressed two missing schema specifically but now I'm missing com.canonical.desktop.interface and solutions I've found don't resolve the issue.

It feels like I've missed something as my install is missing a lot of components. How do I check that everything essential or basic I need is installed or how might I be going about this wrong?

Comment: did you try `sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get upgrade sudo apt-get install`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the image that you installed was not a special "barebones" image? You might want to look at it's contents to ensure it wasn't just a failed install. I would suggest grabbing one of the official images from the [Ubuntu website](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/), and then either copying the missing files or just reinstall.

Comment: I am presuming that it is more than a barebones install considering I followed a [user-friendly install guide](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/795730-how-to-easily-install-ubuntu-on-chromebook-with-crouton) and in other guides this install procedure is followed immediately by doing tasks which I don't have the components for. I will look find out how to use crouton to install a local image that I've downloaded from the official site.

Comment: According to that guide: "The install will be bare-minimum and won’t come with the applications that are packed by distributions, but you can easily install applications from Konsole / terminal. It’s also a good idea to update the system.

sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get upgrade sudo apt-get install"

Comment: Wow, thanks Harm. 
Thanks for helping me to see my blind spots! I guess this is good practice for figuring it all out.